Looking for that old FixOutlook campaign story decades ago that came to nothing
Many years ago, there was a campaign to finally have the terrible HTML rendering and some other annoyances of Outlook fixed. It could have been fixoutlook.org, but I'm not sure about that.
Currently, my main concern is the "double line spacing of death" that to this day still appears whenever Outlook emails are read with any other mail clients. This issue has now also started to appear in the "New Outlook," which is beyond ridiculous.
I clearly remember that the campaign went pretty brutally against Outlook. Then, the Outlook team made a move and sent the campaign team a huge real life physical wall poster with the faces of every single member of the Outlook team, and they all turned out to be nice-looking dudes and girls:

[Edit: maybe it was the other way round and that poster showed the campaign supporters]
This lovely but useless gesture drained all the steam out of the campaign, which then fizzled out in pleasantries and faded into oblivion.
Does anyone happen to remember where this story has been written down and can be found?

A later version of the page you've taken the screenshot of links to this, which I'm guessing is what you mean - they sent a picture of the team with the poster that fixoutlook.org had sent them.

THIS! I still can't believe what can be read there. I couldn't believe it then and I can't believe it now, because it rendered the campaign totally useless. And not a single thing has changed in the decades since then until now. It has only gotten worse.

Original sound from the FixOutlook campaign leader: "I’ve got to give Microsoft an enormous amount of credit for this. They could have ignored our feedback completely, but instead proved they are genuinely listening to our feedback and are prepared to have a bit of fun doing it. It is clear that these guys really do care about giving their customers the best experience possible. Bravo Microsoft." ‍♂️

To be fair, HTML/CSS in emails has always been a terrible idea.  Especially when there's no proper standards for what emails can/should allow through.

Yeah, but now this negligence backfires disastrously against Microsoft themselves because even their own "New Outlook" does not render Outlook emails correctly anymore.
